# How to split a dataframe column into two columns and transform values in one expression using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split a column containing strings into two columns which in this particular case I could do like

`df[['col1','col2']] = df['col1'].str.split('-', expand=True)`.

But I also need to apply a transformation to the second string before storing it in **col2** and this transformation depends on some property of the value in **col1**. Let's for example say that the string in **col2** should be reversed if the length of the string in **col1** is 5.

Is this possible to do this expanding the above expression in some way?

Comment: If you really want to do in one expression, you may consider `df.assign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in @Ynjxsjmh's comment you can use `.assign()`, but you'd need a `lambda` function to give you access to the current state of the dataframe (you need access to both new columns):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ["123-abc"] * 3 + ["12345-abcde"] * 3})

df[["Col1", "Col2"]] = (
    df["Col1"]
    .str.split("-", expand=True)
    .rename(columns={0: "C1", 1: "C2"})
    .assign(C2=lambda df: df["C2"].where(df["C1"].str.len().ne(5), df["C2"].str[::-1]))
)
```